# Next JS - getStaticProps not returning anything

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js with context API and styled components and I can't seem to get `getStaticProps` working.

I have read other posts and often they talk about the custom `_app` which I do have but I never ran into the issue before using context API. I have also tried the `getInitialProps` function and to no avail.
I should also note that even after not including the context wrapper I don't get a response from a function so I'm not at all sure of where to look.

Here is my code. Can you see what's going on?

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export default function Header(props) {
  console.log(props.hi);
  return <div>Hey dis header</div>;
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      hi: 'hello',
    },
  };
}
```

I have tried logging from the function but nothing is logging so I would imagine the problem is that the function isn't running for whatever reason.

Heres my custom `_app` file

```
import { GlobalContextWrapper } from 'context';
import Header from 'components/header/Header';
import App from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <GlobalContextWrapper>
      <Header />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <p>footer</p>
    </GlobalContextWrapper>
  );
}
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  return { ...appProps };
};

export default MyApp;
```

Here is my context file

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';
import initialState from './intialState';
import reducer from './reducer';
import GlobalStyle from '../GlobalStyle';
import theme from '../theme';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

export const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

export function GlobalContextWrapper({ children }) {
  const [globalState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ globalState, dispatch }}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on your code is just getting data in your `_app.js - getInitialProps` and pass to the `Header`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <GlobalContextWrapper>
      <Header data={pageProps.header}/>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <p>footer</p>
    </GlobalContextWrapper>
  );
}
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);


  const headerData = ....

  return { ...appProps, header: headerData };
};
```

Comment: This worked thanks - I was actually using the context api instead. Would you say this is better than using the context api to add the data and then drawing it from the context api?

Comment: I think you should use context or something similar (redux...) for flexibility.
But the important thing is that  if you want your data is initialized from server side for all pages (shared layout purpose) you have to put in _app.js, fetch data and set to your context provider's value. Otherwise, if you fetch data from client side, you can just do client fetching in your Header directly and set context value there

Comment: Yeah i wanted to do that but theres a bit of an issue - I put the call to the context api in a use effect so that it only runs runs however this causes the data to be loaded after the first render which causes problems

Comment: You have to modify a little bit, do the same fetching from server side the same as my example above. Then you pass the props down to the context wrapper, context provider. For example `pageProps.header` into `MyApp`, then `<GlobalContextWrapper value={pageProps.header}>`, then `<GlobalContext.Provider value={props.value}>`. Think it as way to provide default value (fetched from server side) for the context

Comment: Sorry didnt see this. So i should pass whatever is returned from get initial props straight into the context wrapper?  I have been trying this though i still get undefined - I also have requests being made from other pages too, And on these pages there is no context provider, How would i be able to pass it straight into the provider then?

Comment: Let me summarize, if you want to set the data for your context from server side, you have to fetch data in getServerSideProps/getInitialProps and pass to the context value.
If you don't care about SSR, you can set your context value any where, take a look at the official example https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-context-api, they expose the dispatch context for you to set the value

Comment: I saw this example - But i cant see any data fetching thoiugh

Comment: It's just an example but you can extend it. Base on that example, you do the fetching in useEffect then dispatch the value from fetching.
Please tell me your final purpose, what would you like to solve?

Comment: So mainly im looking for a  SSG way of grabbing header (navbar) data from my API and showing it on every page - Right now im using getInitialProps in my _app file which is causing every page to become SSR.  Im actually already using the dispatch and that part is fine - But the trouble is getting the data into my header component in an SSG friendly way

Comment: Now it's clearer. The _app.js is still limited, it does not support something like getStaticProps. Maybe you could have a look at fetching your data in a custom document.js (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#customizing-renderpage), the idea is get data from there and pass to document props, or embed in the head with an JSON object. I'll revise it tomorrow because I have to sleep now. You can try it!

Comment: Let's check out my sample https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-dynamic-layout-props-from-api-qdhqb. Using a custom _document would help you. As in the docs said: _document.js happens in server side of Next.js, actually they were introduced in the old versions of Next.js many times for customizing the layout. Nowadays, people prefer _app.js for static layout, but in your case you want to make it dynamic from API.

Comment: @testingtestinganyone

Comment: Apologies i was at work, This is interesting. Now i can see that the document runs on the server side - So your grabbing the data from the server once on on the first request then passing it through a layout component. This will work well for now, Its annoying there isnt a simple way use getStaticProps for this like the rest of the site but its this looks nice, Thanks man!

Comment: The data works now but the styled components no longer work - Is this due to the fact its all happening serverside now?

Comment: @testingtestinganyone Maybe you have to setup something like this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js

Comment: Maybe in your case, fetch the data from _document and setup _document for styled-components like that link. Or you can only fetch data from _document, and put your main layout in _app.js

Comment: I think I might just hard code the header haha, didn't realize something so simple would turn out to be this difficult

Comment: It's a nice problem, we may meet when building the Headless CMS with the header/categories is fetched dynamically from the API. You could optimize by adding a lru-cache for getting/storing the header data in an amount of time :)

Comment: I think i made a solution! I will write it on codepen and send it to you

Comment: Thank you. Hope we can share something :)

Comment: Hey sorry i was a bit busy. Heres what i done though: I use the file system to write to a JSON file in the root (usingWriteFile) with the data fetched from the CMS. Once i did this i simply fetched this json data from the component. Then i put this component in the _app so that it is on every page. Its working nicely and it only ever writes to the JSON file on build

Comment: export async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
  const hdata = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/header`);
  const hres = await hdata.json();
  const ldata = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/landing-page`);
  const lres = await ldata.json();

  // This will write the latest data to the json file
  const filePath = process.cwd() + '\\headerData.json';
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(hres));

  return {
    props: {
      data: lres,
    },
  };
}

Comment: Nice. I could not think that you choose a simple solution for your question. Maybe you should add `revalidate` option in your getStaticProps to make it have latest data.

Answer (score 12):

The issue was that i was not exporting this function from a page but instead a component and a custom app file.

Does anyone know a way i can get around this? The problem is that i have a header that gets data from a response and i want this header to be shown on every page without having to manually add it to each page along with repeating the getStaticProps function

Comment: Yes you can only use `getInitialProps, getServerSideProps, getStaticProps...` in Next.js pages

Comment: search for next.js persistent layout，there should be a detailed post with codesandbox example on the top written by tailwind.css author.

Comment: In fact, you are looking for something like a global navbar, then you should call your api fetch within the component and update it by `useeffect` and then put it into _app. In this case you shouldn't rely on getInitialProps etc. Use traditional Api request and update it accordingly